# Writing documentation for plain JS class in storybook

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc, storybook

I have just started using Storybook for a UI component lib I am working on. I wanted to extract JSDoc written for JS class methods and properties into Storybook and create a Doc.
Storybook does support creating doc for React components by reading its propTypes. Is there addon or someway to do the same for a JS class.

I am using the latest storybook 6.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like a normal component:

#### form-validators.stories.ts

```
import { FormValidators } from './path';

export default {
  title: 'Components/Form Validators',
  component: FormValidators,
  parameters: {
    previewTabs: { canvas: { hidden: true } },
    docsOnly: true,
  },
} as Meta;

export const Default: Story = () => ({
  template: '<div>Test</div>',
});
```

Or I prefer an MDX file.

#### form-validators.stories.mdx

```
import { ArgsTable } from '@storybook/addon-docs/blocks';
import { Meta } from '@storybook/addon-docs/blocks';
import { FormValidators } from './path';

<Meta
  title="Components/Form Validators"
  parameters={{ previewTabs: { canvas: { hidden: true } } }}
/>

<ArgsTable of={FormValidators} />
```

Comment: With the `.ts` variant, I receive error `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {template}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`
With the `.mdx` variant, I receive `No inputs found for this component. 
Read the docs`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Markdown from the JavaScript class (eg. with [jsdoc-to-markdown](https://github.com/jsdoc2md/jsdoc-to-markdown))
   `jsdoc2md Requester.js >> Requester.md`
2. Create `.mdx` story (eg. `RequesterClass.stories.mdx`)

```
import {Meta} from '@storybook/addon-docs/blocks'
import {Description} from '@storybook/addon-docs'
import Markdown from './Requester.md'

<Meta title="Request/Requester/Class"/>

<Description markdown={Markdown}/>
```